# Upload large video to Picasaweb or Google Photos

Tags: google-drive-api, picasa, google-photos

I saw that Google has release Google Photos, but there is no API for Google Photos, only Picasa Web Album, but the problem is the API support for Picasaweb limit by 100MB, so can we do the cheat upload same as the browser (Picasa web or Google Photos upload) to upload video larger than 100MB?

I've do the analytics the header package of Picasa/Photos when trying to upload a video, look like it's use the resumable technical to upload video.

When I do the analytics of Picasaweb upload, I've saw that it's use the docs.google.com domain to handle the upload, so is there any relating between the Google Drive and Picasa? I mean can we upload video/image to Picasa through Google Drive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While uploading a video to Picasa cannot be achieved either by the Picasa API or Drive API, you can upload the video to your Drive account, with a file of up to 5120GB.

To be able to do this, you should implement a Resumable Upload, splitting the file into chunks of the same size, and uploading one by one. The process is fully documented and described here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resumable

Comment: So that just upload video to Drive account, not Picasa?